# Modifying layout file leads to missing elements

Tags: magento2

I am currently developing my first ever Magento project and have run into a problem I am not able to figure out. Modifying catalog_product_view.xml leads to missing elements such as the review tab and the add to wishlist button. Any reason to why this is happening, and what steps can I take to avoid it? My main problem with it is that it also leads to some extension elements not showing. Thanks.

Comment: Please post code besides only the behavior you need so that we can point answers that can help improve code.

Comment: I have made a copy of catalog_product_view.xml in my custom theme folder and basically any form of modification to the file like adding a referenceContainer or block or moving an element makes the other elements disappear.

Comment: Issue seems to be similar to the one described here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158864/magento-2-add-to-wishlist-not-appearing-on-product-page/273446